# How do i add conditional flag in my script in package.json file?

Tags: angular, npm

I want to run docs, only when a flag is passed like `--doc`.
By default only other scripts should run.
below is my package.json.
On running `build:lib`, I need to add that flag to also build docs

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:doc": "compodoc -p projects/asc-shared-libs/tsconfig.lib.json -d dist/asc-shared-libs/documentation",
    "build:sass": "sass projects/asc-shared-libs/styles.scss projects/asc-shared-libs/styles/styles.css",
    "build:lib": "npm run build:sass  && ng-packagr -p projects/asc-shared-libs/ng-package.json && npm run build:doc && ng serve"
  },
```

Comment: Oh, so you want to alter the function of your script call based on that flag. You can only pass flags INTO the commands that you call. If you want more advanced logic, you might need to create a bash file that gets called instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that, can you give me an idea how can i check for flag here? and add `&& npm run build:doc` only when flag is present?

Comment: I was rewriting my comment as you replied lol. Yeah you would have to write a separate bash file as far as I am aware. You can pass flags into commands but can't really act as a ternary operation directly inline without getting some fancier code than it is probably worth.

Comment: Easiest way, `build:lib:doc` as a script. So you can call just one or the other

Comment: I am calling it after my build finishes, to add the doc inside dist folder, so should be called inline, dont you think?

Comment: Yeah that's a bit more complex than what the package.json scripts are meant for. You aren't really supposed to be able to modify the calling of the scripts with flags, just the operation of the commands called. Like I can run `npm build -- -c production` and it would pass `-c production` to the build command no problem. But if I were to try and pass a flag to the script interpreter, it isn't built to understand flags. If you want to have it always add something to the dist folder after the rest of the lib command runs, yes I would just call it inline.

Comment: From the discussion here, i think we can't add flags in between the scripts
https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518

Comment: correct, the npm scripts are meant for simple automation and flag vs no flag for a specific piece of the command string is overly complicated.